# How To Update Android Button Accessibility Traits

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am curious if it is possible to update the traits attached to an Android button? I currently have a button that is serving as a link out to a web page. For accessibility purposes, when the user highlights the button, it currently reads out

```
"{Title : Learn More}, {Type : Button}, {Hint : Double tap to learn more}"
```

I am curious if it is possible to update the type? By default, the button reads out as a button cause thats what it is. I'm curious if it is possible to update it to read out "Link" instead of "Button"?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I was unable to related information at the time of posting this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597930/how-to-stop-accessibility-from-announcing-android-button-as-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

You should create a custom accessibility delegate compat object, where you can specify it's role by overriding its onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo() method.

You can then set this accessibility delegate to your view.

So, something like this:

```
            @Override
            public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View view, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(view, info);
                if (role != null) {
                    CharSequence role;
                    switch (role) {
                        case Button:
                            roleDescription = "button"
                            break;
                        case Link:
                            roleDescription = "link"
                            break;
                    info.setRoleDescription(roleDescription);
                }
            }
        };
```