# How to override Accessibility class name

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, talkback

I want to prevent `Talkback` from announcing class name for `Button` view. To do so I wrote following logic but it doesn't work

```
fun setAccessibilityDelegate(view: Button?) {
    view?.setAccessibilityDelegate(object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfo?) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info?.contentDescription = getContentDesStartWatching()
            info?.className = ""
        }
    })
}
```

Actual description: "start watching **button, Button** double tap to activate"

Expected description: "**start watching button, double tap to activate**"

**Note:** cannot change the content description to "start watching" as it is getting retrieved from backend

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843919/android-talkback-announces-class-type-at-end-of-content-description/51365163  But you should probably leave it the way it is. Perhaps you think it sounds weird to have the class name announced, but those who use these features may be expecting views to be announced in that way.

Comment: @Michael I am already class name from the backend which I am adding as content description for the Button and hence Button is getting announced twice

Comment: what is the contentDescription?

Comment: why not just add something that strips ' button' from the backend text on the front end if you can't change the backend. This would be the correct description at that point. Don't do Android but I am sure a quick `string.replace(" button", "")` (using the equivalent method) would be simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, used `AccessibilityDelegateCompat` instead of `AccessibilityDelegate`

**Kotlin code:**

```
fun setAccessibilityDelegate(view: View) {
    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(view, object: AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host:View,
                                                       info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info.className = null
            info.contentDescription = getContentDesStartWatching()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't remove the type/class from the last of the readout.